# parsing seconds to mm.ss.00 in r

Tags: r, milliseconds, seconds

I want to convert seconds (performance times)into a mm.ss.00 format. Ideally I'm planning on keeping it in a numerical data format and not a time string (HH.MM.SS etc) so that I can analyses on it using satisitcal models etc.

was hopefull to find a package that could do this for me but with no luck. doing simple math dosent quite give me what im after (eg. dividing by 60).

```
 Distance.km Planned.Time Actual.Time
  <chr>              <dbl>       <dbl>
1 1                   66.4        65.7
2 2                  126.        128. 
3 3                  186.        192. 
4 4                   NA          NA
```

Many Thanks

**EDIT:**

data format I'm trying to achieve is for exmaple 1.06.4 converted from 66.4 seconds

Comment: What is your expected output for the data shared?

Comment: Sorry should have specified, for first observation (row 1 column 2) 01.06.4

Answer (score 0):

Try `lubridate::seconds_to_period` which returns a Period object.

```
lubridate::seconds_to_period(df$Planned.Time)
#[1] "1M 6.40000000000001S" "2M 6S"      "3M 6S"          NA
```

Comment: looked at that function but it dosent give me milliseconds

Comment: It works for me though. I have updated the answer to show you that.

Comment: Yes the code worked for me also but I'm look for a output of 01.06.4 or 1.6.4.

Comment: 01.06.4 is not a valid number nor is 1.6.4. If you want output in that format you need to change it to string.

Comment: Ah I see that makes sense.